# How can I get the key as well as the value in an apex for loop?

Tags: for-loop, key, salesforce, apex-code

I have a map object which stores `<Id, String>` where the Id is a contact Id, and the String is a generated email message.

I have successfully looped through the map and have been able to pull out the values (The String portion) as I iterate through the map.

What I would like to be able to do is also grab the key when I grab the value.  This is very simple to do in most languages, but I can't seem to find out how to do it in apex.

**This is what I have right now:**

```
Map<Id,String> mailContainer = new Map<Id,String>{};

for(String message : mailContainer.values())
{

    // This will return my message as desired
    System.debug(message);

}
```

**What I would like is something like this:**

```
for(String key=>message : mailContainer.values())
{

    // This will return the contact Id
    System.debug(key);

    // This will return the message
    System.debug(message);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Iterate over the keys instead of the values:

```
for (Id id : mailContainer.keySet())
{
    System.debug(id);
    System.debug(mailContainer.get(id));
}
```

Comment: This is so simple.  I can't believe I didn't think to try that.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can't find it because it doesn't exist.  Apex allows iterating over either keys or values but not associations (key, value).

Comment: You can loop through the keys though, and then use those keys to grab the value.  Adam's answer shows this perfectly. You are correct to the extent that I can't iterate over `(key,value)`, but it is still possible to get the same effect with Adam's method.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's another way to accomplish it (slightly more verbose)...

```
    Map<id, string> myMap = Map<id, string> ();

    set<id> keys = myMap.keySet();
    for (id k:keys) {
        system.debug(k +' : '+ myMap.get(k));
    }
```